# col-md-11 with nothing in the remaining 1

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

How do I fill the first 11 columns with a table, but then have the last 1 column be empty?

Right now my HTML is throwing my `<h4>` after my `<div class='col-md-11'` to the right of it just squishing it into the page

my HTML:

```
<nav class='page_element'>
    <div class="table-responsive col-md-11">
        <table>
        </table>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="table-responsive col-md-11">
        <table>
        </table>
    </div>
    <hr>
</nav>
<nav class='page_element'>
    <div class="table-responsive col-md-11">
    </div>
    <h4><strong>Question 3</strong></h4>
....
```

Comment: Can you wrap each of them in `<div class="row">...</div>` blocks?

Comment: not really. I'm using Django's templating system to write the HTML and things would get a little messy

Comment: Is there anyways I could do ```div class='col-md-11 col-md-offset-1'>``` but have the offset be on the right?

Comment: That was actually my next suggestion, to the point that I already had it written out! I have no idea whether it will work, and it's not a very nice solution, but could you add `col-md-offset-1` to the `<h4>`?

Comment: Kind of. But then just the item after it gets thrown in it's place

Comment: Yeah. If I remember correctly, one of the styles that `col-md-11` applies is `float: left`, which does all sorts of havoc when paired with other elements. Hmm. Well, I guess stepping back a little, is there a way you could do this without `col-md-11` and accomplish the desired effect?

Comment: probably, but I'm not very good with css. When I take out ```col-md-11``` the table it too wide, as if it were ```col-md-12``` or something. I have it placed inside a form, and when I take it out, the form has to scroll left to right

Comment: I just figured it out. I have to use ```style="width:95%"``` instead. Thank for the help!

Comment: That's what I was actually going to suggest, but my battery died just before I could. Alas. I'm glad you got it worked out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This all got worked out in comments, but here's an answer for good measure.*

The Bootstrap classes for `col-x-n` really aren't meant to be used as standalone classes. They *work*, sometimes, but, in part because they depend on a styling of `float: left`, they can have some funky behavior when paired with non-`col-x-n` classes. It's best, whenever possible, to wrap them in `row`s.

In that ideal situation, it would look something like this:

```
<nav class='page_element'>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="table-responsive col-md-11">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>

    <h4><strong>Question 3</strong></h4>
</nav>
```

If that isn't, for one reason or another, a good option, I would suggest against using those classes at all. Particularly in a situation like this, they give you a lot of functionality that you don't need, or even want, like the ability to have two columns sit next to each other.

In that case, I would suggest (and I was about to, but then my computer battery died and you beat me to it) using a good-ol'-fashioned `width: x%`. It's always nice to bring that kind of design implementation out from your HTML and into a CSS file, but for the sake of simplicity, a `style` attribute does the same thing.

```
<nav class='page_element'>
    <div class="table-responsive" style="width: 92%">
        ...
    </div>

    <h4><strong>Question 3</strong></h4>
</nav>
```

I picked 92% because that's approximately 11/12, which is what `col-md-11` aims for.

Comment: Thank you for providing a complete answer